# How to use Excel VBA to activate and copy row data from multiple worksheets in multiple workbooks into another workbook's worksheet?

Tags: vba, worksheet-function, excel

I have a series of workbooks, containing a series of worksheets, in which I am needing to consolidate those worksheets into one worksheet (they are all identical columns).

I have the below snippet from my combined() sub that I'm trying to use to access each file, iterate over them, get each worksheet inside, and then copy the contents of each worksheet over to the combined.xlsm file.

My problem is, I'm not quite following how I should activate the workbooks/worksheets with my code. Is my code just not going to work?

```
CombinedWB = "Combined.xlsm"

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set FLS = FSO.GetFolder("c:\path\to\files").Files

Row = 1

For Each F In FLS
    CurrentWB = F.Name

    Windows(CurrentWB).Activate

    If CurrentWB <> CombinedWB Then
        On Error Resume Next
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Worksheets("Combined").Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

        If Row = 1 Then
            Windows(CombinedWB).Activate

            For Each Cell In ActiveSheet.Range("A3")
                Worksheets("Combined").Range("A" & Row).Value = "Name"
                Worksheets("Combined").Range("B" & Row).Value = "Player"
                Worksheets("Combined").Range("C" & Row).Value = Cell.Value
                Worksheets("Combined").Range("D" & Row).Value = Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
                Worksheets("Combined").Range("E" & Row).Value = Cell.Offset(0, 2).Value
                Worksheets("Combined").Range("F" & Row).Value = Cell.Offset(0, 3).Value
                Worksheets("Combined").Range("G" & Row).Value = Cell.Offset(0, 4).Value
                Worksheets("Combined").Range("H" & Row).Value = Cell.Offset(0, 5).Value
                Worksheets("Combined").Range("I" & Row).Value = Cell.Offset(0, 6).Value
                Worksheets("Combined").Range("J" & Row).Value = Cell.Offset(0, 7).Value
                Worksheets("Combined").Range("K" & Row).Value = Cell.Offset(0, 8).Value
                Worksheets("Combined").Range("L" & Row).Value = Cell.Offset(0, 9).Value
                Worksheets("Combined").Range("M" & Row).Value = Cell.Offset(0, 10).Value
                Worksheets("Combined").Range("N" & Row).Value = Cell.Offset(0, 11).Value
                Worksheets("Combined").Range("O" & Row).Value = Cell.Offset(0, 12).Value
                Worksheets("Combined").Range("P" & Row).Value = Cell.Offset(0, 13).Value
            Next

            Windows(CurrentWB).Activate

            Row = 2
        End If

        For J = 1 To Sheets.Count
            Player = Sheets(J).Cells(1).Parent.Name
            Injury = Sheets(J).Range("A5").Value
            InjuryDate = Sheets(J).Range("B5").Value
            For Each Cell In Sheets(J).Range("A5:A100")
                Windows(CombinedWB).Activate

                If IsEmpty(Cell.Offset(0, 2).Value) <> True Then
                    Worksheets("Combined").Range("A" & Row).Value = Name
                    Worksheets("Combined").Range("B" & Row).Value = Player
                    Worksheets("Combined").Range("C" & Row).Value = Injury
                    Worksheets("Combined").Range("D" & Row).Value = InjuryDate
                    Worksheets("Combined").Range("E" & Row).Value = Cell.Offset(0, 2).Value
                    Worksheets("Combined").Range("F" & Row).Value = Cell.Offset(0, 3).Value
                    Worksheets("Combined").Range("G" & Row).Value = Cell.Offset(0, 4).Value
                    Worksheets("Combined").Range("H" & Row).Value = Cell.Offset(0, 5).Value
                    Worksheets("Combined").Range("I" & Row).Value = Cell.Offset(0, 6).Value
                    Worksheets("Combined").Range("J" & Row).Value = Cell.Offset(0, 7).Value
                    Worksheets("Combined").Range("K" & Row).Value = Cell.Offset(0, 8).Value
                    Worksheets("Combined").Range("L" & Row).Value = Cell.Offset(0, 9).Value
                    Worksheets("Combined").Range("M" & Row).Value = Cell.Offset(0, 10).Value
                    Worksheets("Combined").Range("N" & Row).Value = Cell.Offset(0, 11).Value
                    Worksheets("Combined").Range("O" & Row).Value = Cell.Offset(0, 12).Value
                    Worksheets("Combined").Range("P" & Row).Value = Cell.Offset(0, 13).Value
                    Row = Row + 1
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End If
Next
```

**EDIT**

Here is the final working code (thanks to mwolfe02):

```
Sub Combine()
    Dim J As Integer
    Dim Sport As String
    Dim Player As String
    Dim Injury As String
    Dim InjuryDate As String
    Dim Row As Integer
    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim FLS As Object
    Dim CurrentWB As String
    Dim CombinedWB As String
    Dim CombinedWBTemp As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim cwb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cws As Worksheet

    CombinedWB = "Combined.xlsm"
    CombinedWBTemp = "~$" & CombinedWB

    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set FLS = FSO.GetFolder("c:\path\to\files").Files
    Set cwb = Workbooks(CombinedWB)

    Set cws = cwb.Worksheets("Combined")

    cws.Range("A1:Z3200").Clear

    Row = 1

    For Each F In FLS
        CurrentWB = F.Name

        If CurrentWB <> CombinedWB And CurrentWB <> CombinedWBTemp Then
            On Error Resume Next

            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(CurrentWB)

            On Error Resume Next
            If Not wb.Sheets("Combined") Is Nothing Then
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                wb.Sheets("Combined").Delete
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            End If

            If Row = 1 Then
                For Each Cell In wb.Sheets(1).Range("A3")
                    cws.Range("A" & Row).Value = "Sport"
                    cws.Range("B" & Row).Value = "Player"
                    cws.Range("C" & Row).Value = Cell.Value
                    cws.Range("D" & Row).Value = Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
                    cws.Range("E" & Row).Value = Cell.Offset(0, 2).Value
                    cws.Range("F" & Row).Value = Cell.Offset(0, 3).Value
                    cws.Range("G" & Row).Value = Cell.Offset(0, 4).Value
                    cws.Range("H" & Row).Value = Cell.Offset(0, 5).Value
                    cws.Range("I" & Row).Value = Cell.Offset(0, 6).Value
                    cws.Range("J" & Row).Value = Cell.Offset(0, 7).Value
                    cws.Range("K" & Row).Value = Cell.Offset(0, 8).Value
                    cws.Range("L" & Row).Value = Cell.Offset(0, 9).Value
                    cws.Range("M" & Row).Value = Cell.Offset(0, 10).Value
                    cws.Range("N" & Row).Value = Cell.Offset(0, 11).Value
                    cws.Range("O" & Row).Value = Cell.Offset(0, 12).Value
                    cws.Range("P" & Row).Value = Cell.Offset(0, 13).Value
                Next

                Row = 2
            End If

            For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
                Player = ws.Cells(1).Parent.Name
                Injury = ws.Range("A5").Value
                InjuryDate = ws.Range("B5").Value
                For Each Cell In ws.Range("A5:A100")
                    If IsEmpty(Cell.Offset(0, 2).Value) <> True Then
                        cws.Range("A" & Row).Value = wb.Name
                        cws.Range("B" & Row).Value = Player
                        cws.Range("C" & Row).Value = Injury
                        cws.Range("D" & Row).Value = InjuryDate
                        cws.Range("E" & Row).Value = Cell.Offset(0, 2).Value
                        cws.Range("F" & Row).Value = Cell.Offset(0, 3).Value
                        cws.Range("G" & Row).Value = Cell.Offset(0, 4).Value
                        cws.Range("H" & Row).Value = Cell.Offset(0, 5).Value
                        cws.Range("I" & Row).Value = Cell.Offset(0, 6).Value
                        cws.Range("J" & Row).Value = Cell.Offset(0, 7).Value
                        cws.Range("K" & Row).Value = Cell.Offset(0, 8).Value
                        cws.Range("L" & Row).Value = Cell.Offset(0, 9).Value
                        cws.Range("M" & Row).Value = Cell.Offset(0, 10).Value
                        cws.Range("N" & Row).Value = Cell.Offset(0, 11).Value
                        cws.Range("O" & Row).Value = Cell.Offset(0, 12).Value
                        cws.Range("P" & Row).Value = Cell.Offset(0, 13).Value
                        Row = Row + 1
                    End If
                Next
            Next

            wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
        End If
    Next

    Windows(CombinedWB).Activate
    Sheets("Combined").Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: Downvote on question is retribution related to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12131139/convert-this-formula-to-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problems are caused by using the `.Activate` method.  There is no need for that in what you are trying to do.  Code created using the macro recorder is littered with `.Activate` calls, but they are generally a bad idea when writing code yourself.

Try something more like this:

```
Const CombinedWB As String = "Combined.xlsm"
Dim FSO As Object, FLS As Object, F As Object
Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
Dim cwb As Workbook   'This will be our combined workbook'    
Dim cws As Worksheet   'This will be the combined worksheet'    

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set FLS = FSO.GetFolder("c:\path\to\files").Files
Set cwb = Workbooks.Open(CombinedWB)
'Use the following line if there is just a single combined worksheet'
'  and it is in the combined workbook'
Set cws = cwb.Worksheets("Combined")


For Each F In FLS
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(F.Name)

    If F.Name <> CombinedWB Then
        ....
        'Use the following line if each workbook has a combined worksheet'
        Set cws = wb.Worksheets("Combined")  
        For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
            cws.Range("A1") = cws.Range("A1") + ws.Range("A1")
            ....
        Next ws
    End If
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
Next F
```

Comment: @mwolfe02 - Why are they are bad idea? (just wondering) I guess I'm not seeing how I can call the Worksheets("Combined") AND get the current cell value from the original worksheet on the same line. This is where I'm stuck.

Comment: In and of themselves they are not bad.  Where you run into trouble is when you rely on the `Activate` method to put Excel into a specific state (namely one where some sheet or workbook is activated).  This will almost certainly cause problems when a user activates a different workbook/worksheet in the middle of a running process.  Now all of a sudden your code thinks it is working on Worksheet "A" (because that is what it activated) but the user clicked on Worksheet "B" so all the stuff you programmed to happen on Worksheet "A" is instead happening on Worksheet "B".

Comment: Do I need to prefix all of my calls to the combined workbook with cws? As in, cws.Application.DisplayAlerts instead of Application.DisplayAlerts?

Comment: It depends on where the specific item falls within the object model.  You would not need to prefix the Application object because that is "above" the worksheet object.  However, you'd need to prefix calls to the Range() property because otherwise they default to the active worksheet.

Comment: Oh that's right. It's working somewhat with your suggested improvements and some other things I've noticed. Making progress.

Comment: Thanks mwolfe02! You really helped me out. :) I posted my final procedure in my question.