# Transferring one sheet information to another

Tags: excel, vba

I have an dropped down list with the names of different sheets. I would like to make it such that when I select the appropriate name in sheet, the contents of another sheet is shown on sheet1. Is anyone familiar with such a code or if it is possible? It is actually many hidden sheets of recipes where the user can view the different recipes all in one sheet whichever the user selects. The format of the recipes can be assumed to be the same.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Excel VBA to activate and copy row data from multiple worksheets in multiple workbooks into another workbook's worksheet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5261817/how-to-use-excel-vba-to-activate-and-copy-row-data-from-multiple-worksheets-in-mu)

Answer (score 1):

To make it work, you'll need to use [INDIRECT](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/indirect.htm) and [ADDRESS](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/address.php) functions.

If we have the sheet name stored in Sheet1.A2 cell, then the code would be like this for the cell B2:

```
=INDIRECT($A$2&"!"&ADDRESS(ROW(B2);COLUMN(B2)))
```

This could should be copied across the range you want to take from other sheets.

Rgds

Comment: Ah, Thank you very much. I have not come across these functions before, but I think I know how they work. ill find out more and apply them. thanks!

Comment: Great. If you have problems applying them, just add a comment here... otherwise we can set this topic as answered.

Comment: Hi Tiago, can I check with you, the formula returns me back one cell. Is there any way i can return a selection of cells. I cant seem to do it my simply selecting them.

Comment: @Jeylani, simply drag this formula across the range you want to copy it. You'll need to do it first in a row level and then in a column level. Let's say you want to take the data from the other sheets between cells B2 and G10. Drag the formula first from B2 to B10, then select this range (B2 to B10) and drag it till G10.
Voilà, you're taking data for the whole range.

Comment: @Tiago, thank you so much for your help, it was of great help.

Comment: @Jeylani, if this topic answered your question, please set it as 'answered'.... then the community will know that this topic does not need further discussion.