# How would I display selected row on a new work sheet?

Tags: excel, excel-2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to edit info in cells displayed via macro code in Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352391/how-to-edit-info-in-cells-displayed-via-macro-code-in-excel)

I'm just a bit stumped.

I have a large excel table with quite a few columns. The first column item is a 'company name' and then the other columns contain details such as 'website', 'contact name', 'email address', 'query', 'comments' etc etc.

It's a bit confusing and difficult scrolling all the way to the right to see the info in the columns at the end.

I was wondering if there would be any way I could maybe take all the info from a single row and display it on sheet two? Perhaps displaying it vertically, so that I wouldn't have to scroll to the right to see all the company details.

What I would like, is to be able to look through the main spreadsheet to find a 'company name' and then maybe if I click on that company name, all the info from that row would show up in a nice table on sheet two.

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways to do it, let's see if one of them fits your needs:

- **Freeze pane**: Click in cell B1 and then 'view / freeze pane'.
- **Split:** It will split (duh) your spreadsheet.

I believe one of these might fit your request. hope it helps!

Rgds

Edit: Similar question [HERE](https://superuser.com/questions/228751/how-can-header-cells-in-excel-be-pinned-or-frozen).

Comment: These are kind of handy, but not really what I had in mind. I was hoping to be able to highlight a row on the 1st sheet and then view that specific row on sheet 2 by itself.

I've managed to do it with a macro, but just having trouble now, as if I alter the info on sheet two, it doesn't update the info on the first sheet. 

Is there maybe a simpler way? Maybe just using a formula in the cells on sheet two, to link to a cell in the highlighted row on sheet one, so that the info on sheet 2 changes depending on which row you have highlighted on sheet 1.

Comment: @Ade, maybe this topic may fits this approach you're trying to apply:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319939/transferring-one-sheet-information-to-another/5320642#5320642

Comment: I've updated my question here: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352391/how-to-edit-info-in-cells-displayed-via-macro-code-in-excel) to show a macro that I'm now using. Still having a few issues with it though!